# Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am implementing custom pagination like this:

```
<ul class="pagination">
     <li ng-repeat="item in numberOfPages(items.listOfGoods.length/pageSize)">
         <a href="">{{item}}</a>
     </li>
</ul>
```

But it is showing this error when using ng-repeat:

```
Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting
```

Comment: Can i see your full code?

Comment: you are running into an infinite loop. please check with the syntax

Comment: <ul class="pagination">
      <li ng-repeat="item in numberOfPages(items.listOfGoods.length/pageSize)"><a href="">{{item}}</a>
      </li>
 </ul>

Comment: <li ng-repeat="item in numberOfPages(items.listOfGoods.length/pageSize)">

Comment: Sorry, You need to read this. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

Basicly you arent asking the ng-repeat to iterate over a collection, but to iterate over a function call again and again and again. It won't call on the function once and then repeat item in , but it will call the function for every iteration. That way it keeps going and keeps going in an infinite loop.

Solve this by storing the function data in a variable, then use ng-repeat on that variable. e.g:

```
$scope.pages = numberOfpages(items.listsOfGoods.length/pagesize);
```

and then in your html:

```
<li ng-repeat="page in pages">
    <a href="">{{item}}</a>
```